# Accessible way to link blog post teasers to the full blog post page

Tags: html, hyperlink, accessibility, blogs, semantic-markup

Which one is the best way to approach links on a blog listing to improve accessibility?

1. Only a link on the "Read More" button
2. An `<a>` tag surrounding the entire list item, to make every area clickable
3. Everything with its own `<a>` tag

[image: Images with exemples of the list above]

I was been reading about this and the first option sounds like the best for screen readers, but isn't nice to not be able to click on the title or text to enter the post.

I think that the second options its the best, but that approach conflits with the share buttons, because link inside links isn't valid HTML.

And the third one looks bloated and mess with the screen reader.

Comment: I am a big supporter of a clickable Title, Image and Read More button. I would go for a slimmed down version of 3.

Comment: Option 3 is perfect as most of the blogging platforms are following this pattern. As it will also help you to create some more clicks to your website.

Comment: I think this may be too broad to answer and might be a better fit for [UX Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).  Right now, it's too opinion based.

Comment: I would actually be against everything being an anchor.  If I am using accessibility tools and trying to navigate from anchor to anchor, I don't want to get stuck in a gigantic list of anchors.  I also don't like 2 because the whole article isn't a link to a document, only the read more is.

Comment: I was researching this, looking at some sites, ang sites like Engadget uses an anchor tag above all content with position absolute to be clickable, and some z-index to put other links above this one. Looks like a nice solution to follow

Comment: I have flagged this to be migrated, this question is not about programming and does not belong on SO.

Comment: @Clint: I think this question is fine. HTML / semantic markup / accessibility are on-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @unor I think you're right. I would cancel it if I could. The flag is likely to age away anyways.

Comment: Noting that in option two, having a `<button>` inside an `<a>` is invalid HTML. Also hoping to get additional fresh answers to this question. It's something I think about a lot and there doesn't seem to be a clear "best practice".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For people using keyboard navigation, it's best to only have one link with good and short alternative text, like

```
<a href="#" aria-label="Read more about Original post title">Read more</a>
```

But this does not prevent you from using the `onclick` event on the outer div to make the full snippet clickable in order to improve mouse navigation.

Comment: The `aria-label` completely overrides the inner text so screen readers will just say "go to original post title".  That's fine for screen readers but makes the link very difficult to select using speech recognition assistive technology.  The (sighted) user will see "read more" but if they say "click read more", it won't work because the accessible name for the link is not "read more", it's "go to original...".  To make **both** screen readers and speech recog happy, you can do something like `<a href='#'>Read more <span class='sr-only'>about blah blah blog post</span></a>`.

Comment: @slugolicious You're perfectly right. I will have to test some speech recognition software to see their behavior with more than a "read more" link.